# InvalidFileException error when iterating through directory with openpyxl.load_workbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have a directory of .xls and .xlsx files I am trying to load into Python with the openpyxl module. My code is as follows:

`for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if i.endswith(".xls") or i.endswith(".xlsx"):
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(i)`

When I run this code I am receiving the following error:

`raise InvalidFileException(unicode(e))
InvalidFileException: "There is no item named 'xl/styles.xml' in the archive"`

I am able to load these same files successfully with openpyxl one at a time, but not in a loop.

Thank you in advance for any help.

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if os.path.isfile(i):
        if i.endswith(".xls") or i.endswith(".xlsx"):
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), i))
```

1. Since `os.listdir()` returns the names of both files and directories, its a good idea to check whether the given item is a file or not before proceeding.
2. Replaced `openpyxl.load_workbook(i)` with `openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), i))` to pass the absolute path of the matched file as relative paths sometimes create problems in file handling

**Note:** Consider updating **openpyxl** and changing the **.xls** extension to **.xlsx** or **.xlrd** to ensure compatibility with the latest version of the library.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I am still seeing the same error.  `raise InvalidFileException(unicode(e))

InvalidFileException: "There is no item named 'xl/styles.xml' in the archive"` I tried the same process with the xlrd module and found success. It leads me to believe it is related to something specific in the openpyxl module.

Comment: @Venetian Do you have the latest version of openpyxl?

Comment: I don't think so. I was recommended to use Anaconda and the Spyder IDE for Python. Anaconda for Python 3.4 comes with openpyxl v. 1.8.5, which isn't the latest version. I'll update the package through the Anaconda command prompt and retry. Thank you.

Comment: So I upgraded from 1.8.5 to 2.0.2 using the Anaconda command prompt. Still did not work. I upgraded to openpyxl 2.3.0 in IDLE and ran the same code. The error I received is was `openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support the old .xls file format, please use xlrd to read this file, or convert it to the more recent .xlsx file format.`

Comment: @Venetian Do what it says, open the **.xls** file in a newer version of MS-Excel (>2003) and save it as a **.xlsx** file.

Comment: Thank you, this works. On a larger scale, it looks like I'll be using xlrd if I am dealing with many .xls files

Comment: @Venetian Let me update the answer so that the question can be closed :)

Comment: Sure, will do. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you update your version of openpyxl. It hasn't been a requirement to have a `styles.xml` in an archive for a while.